# JSTL Custom Tag for request Object

Tags: jsp, request, jsp-tags, jst

I have task as the jsp request object attributes need to customized. like request.setAttribute("userName"); We need to get userName using JSTL and it should be customized. i need to do it through JSTL. we should not use request object. Is it possile through custom JSTL.

Comment: So are you saying , you want to get userName attribute in JSP using JSTL ?

Comment: Then just use `${userName}`

Comment: yes. amit. It got worked. Thank you.